# What loss term might enforce interpretability?

Tags: machine-learning, graphs, mathematics

A neural net can be interpreted as a weighted directed graph. Interpretability of this neural net could be measured using properties of that graph. In particular, "modularity" might be useful, which I could formalize as "A graph is modular if a small number of edges can be removed in order to split it into smaller graphs that are themselves modular.". This would allow a reader to understand small portions of the neural net at a time because they only interface with the rest in limited ways.

My question is: What differentiable numeric properties of weighted directed graphs encapsulate interpretability and can thus be used as a loss term to enforce interpretability?

Comment: In a feedforward fully connected layer I could imagine this being the number of connections, basically making it not fully connected anymore. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: No. I don't expect the optimal cuts to cut along layers. The mere number of connections is not differentiable, though the sum of their weights would be. (Even then, it probably makes more sense to measure the amount of information flowing through those edges.) I'd like the net to decompose into a hierarchy of modules so one can assemble an understanding of what it's doing.